# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Tags: forms, angular, autocomplete

I am creating a form in Angular 2 with an input with autocompletion. I would like to get the data of the autocompletion services  in this input but when, I am running it I got this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

**app.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
       @Input('group') 
        public group: FormGroup; 
     formatList(data: any):string { 
            return `<span>${data["value"]}</span>`; 
        } 
        searchResult(search:string):Observable<any> { 
            return this.autoCompleteService.search(search); 
      } 

      sendInitiator(item) {
         ....
       }
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private autoCompleteService:AutoCompleteInitiatorService
      ) {
         this.searchResult = this.searchResult.bind(this); 
         this.autoCompleteService = autoCompleteService; 
      }
    }
```

**app.component**

```
 <form id="Form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">
      label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" [formGroup]="group">
                        <div class="input-group-item">
                            <input class="input" 
                                auto-complete require 
                                formControlName="initiator" 
                                [source]="searchResult"  
                                (valueChanged)="sendInitiator($event)" 
                                name="initiator" 
                                auto-complete-placeholder="Select One" 
                                value-property-name="id" 
                                display-property-name="value" 
                                min-chars="2" [list-formatter]="formatList" /> 
                        </div> 
    <form>
```

Any help/pointing me in the right direction would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate form with formBuilder, like this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kc2mqu52ZS0X2E2JJQ0O?p=preview)

```
this.group = this.formBuilder.group({
 initiator: ''
})
```